# shortcode doesn't work wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have this shortcode code..

```
function codeThree($attr,$content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'style' => 'design1',
  'title' => 'Here is where the title will be reside..',
  'image' => 'codethreeimg'
   ), $atts));

$dir = get_template_directory_uri();

return '<div class="codethree extend" style="background: transparent url('.$dir.'/images/'.$style.'.jpg) no-repeat top center;"><img class="codethreeimg" src="'.$dir.'/'.$image.'" /><p class="codethreep"><h2 class="codethreetitle">'.$title.'</h2><br/>'.do_shortcode($content).'</p></div>';

}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('codethree', 'codeThree');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

and this for displaying them..

```
[codethree style="design1" title="Hi, I'm Armando Gutierrez, #1 Personal Trainer in Torrance & LA, and Body Transformation Specialist." image="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Profile.png"]some contents here[/codethree]
```

as you can see, this:

```
'style' => 'design1',
'title' => 'Here is where the title will be reside..',
'image' => 'codethreeimg'
```

will be default, if user doesn't specify there define content on those array fields, but what happens, the default content was instead displayed although those fields has been filled by the user define content.

```
[codethree style="design1" title="Hi, I'm Armando Gutierrez, #1 Personal Trainer in Torrance & LA, and Body Transformation Specialist." image="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Profile.png"]some contents here[/codethree]
```

Could someone check my codes and at least tell me whats wrong please? I'm open to any suggestions, ideas and recommendations! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay, some minor mistake regarding the code, anyway heres the update as I found a solution.

this

    function codeThree($attr,$content)

change into

    function codeThree($atts,$content)

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need the add_shortcode to be attached to a hook. Instead of:

```
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('codethree', 'codeThree');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Try just `add_shortcode('codethree', 'codeThree');` and lose the rest. At least, that's how I've always done mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one shortcode why creating a function to register? why don't you just use the `add_shortcode('codethree', 'codeThree');`
here is the example of one of my shortcodes that i do not even to my plugins but to accomplish anything i want this one is just for making a content in a post visible only to the non registered members of the site

```
add_shortcode('wageni','for_guests_only');
 function for_guests_only($atts,$content){
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
    return $content;
}
    return '';
```

}